# how to clone or mirror a gitosis server

Tags: git, gitosis, mirror, git-clone

I have a working gitosis server someone else setup and I want to replicate that server using a Virtual Box VM setup on Ubuntu so I can experiment with modifying it before changing the live server. I have root access to the live gitosis server so I can tar the /home/git directory and copy it to my VM if needed.

So what exactly do I need to do to replicate or mirror the gitosis server? What exactly needs to be copied or installed from scratch. I'm not talking about packages installed by apt-get I'm talking about stuff the gitosis install would do. For example, can I simply copy /home/git from the server and use that or should I copy /home/git then replace repositories
using "git clone --mirror"?

Also am I missing anything else here? For example, if the server starts git-daemon using a special script I have to copy that also I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would install gitosis on the new server, just like normal, and than copy your repositories directory and the "admin repo" over.  You could also push the repositories and "admin repo" over.

I haven't done this personally, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.